# cannot specify location of bucket when creating a glcoud storage bucket

Tags: gcloud, google-api-client

The following code, I would think, would build a bucket in the us-west region but on my google console the region is listed as multi-regional.

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.location = 'us-west2-a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.location = 'us-west2-a'
```

The problem in your code sample is that you have specified 'us-west2-a' which is a zone name instead of puting 'us-west2' which is the region (location) name.

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.location = 'us-west2'
```

By changing to 'us-west2' it should create your bucket in the desired location.

References:

[Storage - Location sample code](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html)

[Google Cloud Locations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations)